# how to merge two collections by updating a value on duplicates

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have this class:

```
class A{
 int count=0;


 //equals and hashCode implemented
}
```

create two collections:

```
Collection<A>  collection1;//something
Collection<A>  collection2;//something
```

concatenate the collections:

```
Stream.concat(collection1.stream(), collection2.stream())
                //do something here???
                .distinct()
                .sorted(new Comparator<A>() {
                  @Override
                  public int compare(A o1, A o2) {

                     return new Integer(o1.count).compareTo(new Integer(o2.count));
                  }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to merge these two lists and if there any duplicates, I want to update integer `count;` the above code gets rid of duplicates completely

For example, 
say we got an object in both collection1 and collection2 that are equal `(o1.equals(o2) == true)` . One has `count=10` and the other one has `count=20` I want to have a collection of distinct objects with that object to have `count=30`

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it clearer, could you gimme a suggestion so I can edit the question, thx

Comment: Are you comparing the counts AND incrementing the counts when there is a match?  I think perhaps you need something besides count to distinguish your classes.

Comment: @BillK say we got dups, one with count=10 and one with count=20. I want to keep one with count=30! hope that makes sense mate

Comment: The question is, how do you identify "That Object?"  It looks like you are identifying your objects by the count--I'm intuiting that by your compare definition, so the two with count=10 and count=20 would not match and they wouldn't be added to make 30, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with your current approach, instead you can use the `toMap` collector:

```
Stream.concat(collection1.stream(), collection2.stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),Function.identity(),
       (left, right) -> {
          left.setCount(left.getCount() + right.getCount());
          return left;
       })).values()
         .stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(A::getCount))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses [Stream.concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) to merge `collection1` and `collection2` together into a single `Stream<A>`.

We then call the [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector where the first [Function.identity()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) selects the elements of the source as the keys i.e `A` and the second [Function.identity()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) also selects the elements of the source as the values; again `A`, so at this point, you can visualise the data as `Map<A, A>`.

The function `(left, right) -> { ... }` is known as the merge function, this is the place where if two given objects are equal we then say take the count of the first element and take the count of the second element, add them together and assign the new value back to one of the elements we are going to keep and then discard the other.

because you've overridden `equals` and `hashcode`, we don't need to *explicitly* call it, instead, the `equals` method will be called *implicitly* to determine if two given objects are equal.

once we've collected the elements to a `Map<A, A>`, we then call the `values()` method to retrieve a `Collection<A>`, this then enables us to create a stream from it with the `stream()` method and further enables us to sort the streams elements with the sorted method and finally collect it to a `List<A>` with the [toList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) collector.

Comment: mate, gonna try this when I get home and will let you know, ty

Comment: +1 good approach. Worth mentioning the need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for this approach to function if you don't want some confusing results.

Comment: @arthur couldn't agree more :). the OP has already mentioned that equals and hashCode are implemented.  this is mentioned in class `A` as a comment.

Comment: @Aominè it works great mate, would you please explain to me how this code actually works, I just can't get my head around it!

Comment: @Aominè e.g. how/where `equals()` and `hashCode()` are used?

Comment: @nafas see edit, if you have any further questions, feel free to ask :).